# Is there a term for head-on collisions that don't seem head-on in the lab frame?

Tags: terminology, collision

I have found that generally, you can speak of 'Head-on' collisions if they are head-on (in any frame of reference) and 'glancing', 'oblique', or 'non-head-on' collisions if they are not (the impact parameter is larger than 0). But is there a term for collisions that are not head-on in the lab frame, but are in the center-of-mass frame of reference (meaning the absolute velocities in the lab frame don't point toward each other, but the relative velocity is along the line of impact)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As long as one of the particles is initially stationary in the lab frame, then head-on is a thing that is agreed between lab frame and CoM frame. i.e. glancing is also agreed between lab frame and CoM frame.

If you want things to be more general than that, then the concept itself becomes nebulous. There is a definition of head-on for CoM frame alone, and maybe you want to use that to define it for the general case.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, two particles with the same velocity $v_y$, and equal but opposite $v_x$ would not be head-on? Instead, it would only be head-on if you go to the center-of-mass frame. I thought this collision would be considered head-on in all frames of reference, because it was head-on in one frame of reference, but if not then that would solve my problem.

Comment: I thought very hard about that case too when I wrote my answer. Your way of framing it required that they have the same mass; there is a way to fix it that it will not make this requirement, and yes, it is the other case whereby it is obviously a head-on collision. But once you consider any more general, it becomes difficult to see.